# Given a sorted array of integers find subarrays such that the largest elements of the subarrays are within some distance of the smallest

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

For example, given an array

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9]
```

and an integer
`i = 2`. Find maximal subarrays where the distance between the largest and the smallest elements is at most i. The output for the example above would be:

```
[1,2,3] [7,8,9]
```

The subarrays are maximal in the sense given two subarrays A and B. There exists no element b in B such that A + b satisfies the condition given. Does there exist a non-polynomial time algorithm for said problem ?

Comment: What do you mean by `non-polynomial time`? What time is for you own solution?

Comment: I mean time that is smaller than O(n^2)

Comment: OMG... I missed that your array is always sorted. In this case you can use method of two pointers without additional structures, because you always know min/max in the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem might be solved in linear time using method of two pointers and two deques storing indices, the first deque keeps minimum, another keeps maximum in sliding window.

Deque for minimum (similar for maximum):

```
current_minimum = a[minq.front]
```

Adding i-th element of array:  //at the right index

```
while (!minq.empty and a[minq.back] > a[i]): 
   //last element has no chance to become a minimum because newer one is better
   minq.pop_back
minq.push_back(i)
```

Extracting j-th element:    //at the left index

```
if (!minq.empty and minq.front == j)
    minq.pop_front
```

So min-deque always contains non-decreasing sequence.

Now set `left` and `right` indices in 0, insert index 0 into deques, and start to move `right`.  At every step add index in order into deques, and check than `left..right` interval range is good. When range becomes too wide (min-max distance is exceeded), stop moving `right` index, check length of the last good interval, compare with the best length.

Now move `left` index, removing elements from deques. When max-min becomes good, stop `left` and start with `right` again. Repeat until array end.